# Change user_nickname for author page link

Tags: database, users, forms

I have a page where user can change their personal info. Now I want to give them a possibility to change their personal page link by changing theire user nickname. So I want to create simple form with two fields and one button. This form will change this column in this table:

[image]

```
<form role="form" name="profile_name_form" id="profile_name_form" action="#">

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="user_nicename" id="user_nicename" />

<label>Pin</label>
<input type="text" name="pin_code" id="pin_code" />

<div id="update_message"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="update_profile_name();">Update</button>

</form>
```

Firts field for nickname and second field for checking pin-code. So, user can change his nicname only if he know personal pin. I have another database "DB_test" with table "list" where only two columns: "profile_id" and "pin".

[image]

So if user will put correct username and pin-code to his profile form it will update "user_nicname" in WP database.

Example:

[image]

Short Questions:

1. How to update "user_nicname" in "wp_users" table? It acan be the simple example, only important part of jQuery.ajax with response messages and other functions of this form.
2. How to verify username and pin-code from a separate database? or a table inside current website if it will be faster and easier?

Thanks a lot for any helpful information!

Comment: to save a pine code for each user you can use [update_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) and to update the nicename : [wp_update_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user)

Comment: @Kaperto tank's, but I don't need to save pin-code, I want that they will have a possibility to change profile link only if they have a pin-code. I will add their name and pin-code to the table by myself.